# Self extracting installer permission denied during run

Tags: permissions

I apologize if this is a duplicate of anything. I did do many searches on google, this site and Stack Overflow. I am having a problem running a self extracting installer, even with sudo and proper permissions (tried both `chmod 777` and `chmod a+x`).

Here is an output of the attempts:

```
[xxxxx@nameless target]$ chmod a+x Toolkit_install.bin 
[xxxxx@nameless target]$ sudo ./Toolkit_install.bin 
[sudo] password for xxxxx: 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
./Toolkit_install.bin: line 124: test: too many arguments
Uncompressing Toolkit v3.0.1 Installer.....................................................
./Toolkit_install.bin: line 380: ./install.sh: Permission denied
```

The problem seems to be that I need to give install.sh permissions, but I do not know how to give permissions to a file that is dynamically created by the installer.

I've tried giving the directory permissions and also created install.sh ahead of time and giving it permissions.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the following command :

`chmod -R 777 /<installation_dir>`

or, run the bash with root permissions by typing :

`sudo bash <script_name>`

Comment: Both still generate the same permissions issues. But thanks for the suggestions nonetheless!

Comment: did you try `sudo sh Toolkit_install.bin` ?

Comment: Yes, it produced the same issue.

Comment: Try modifying permissions through GUI. GO to terminal and type `sudo nautilus`. Now navigate to your folder and give it read and write permissions. Similarly, do it to the bin file too. Now, go to terminal, type `sudo su` and try executing the binary using `sh Toolkit_install.bin`

Comment: Permission denied after giving the folder and the .bin both read and write permissions.

Comment: I think you have a broken script. Try building what you're trying to install from source.

Comment: Yes I fear the same. Thank you for the help, I'll contact the creator.